# Why is my named form not being returned?

Tags: javascript, dom

In the following code, I get an error

> cannot read property "Area Sorted" of undefined

when I call the line

```
document.SortingForm.AreaSorted.value = Names.join("\n");
```

I've been over the code a hundred of times and I don't see why this is happening. I would really appreciate any help with this.

**sort.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<title>Sort</title>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sort.js">
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Sorting String Arrays</h1>
<p>Enter two or more names in the field below,
and the sorted list of names will appear in the
text area.</p>
<form name=”SortingForm”>
Name:
<input type="text" name="FieldWord" size="20" />
<input type="button" name="ButtonAddWord" value="Add" onClick="SortNames();" />
<br/>
<h2>Sorted Names</h2>
<textarea name=”AreaSorted” cols=”60” rows=”10” >
The sorted names will appear here.
</textarea>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**sort.js**

```
var Names = new Array();

function SortNames()
{
    Name = document.getElementsByName("FieldWord")[0].value;
    Names.push(Name);
    Names.sort();
    document.SortingForm.AreaSorted.value = Names.join("\n");
}
```

Comment: Does is matter that `SortingForm` has strange speechmarks around it?

Comment: @Oliver OH MY GOD! How on Earth did you spot that! I was writing an e-mail in my Native language which has different "'s than English and that's what was causing the error. You're a genius. Post that as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @W.K.S It's a little suprising that it makes a difference. If I was defining HTML, I'd allow all all speechmark characters to be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have weird speechmarks around the name of the form: `”`. I'm a little suprised that using these is not valid though.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try adding an id to the textarea and use:

```
document.getElementById('AreaSorted');
```

That should always work, regardless of the form being there.

Also the quotes before and after the form's name seem to be off, try retyping them.

Answer (score 0):

AreaSorted isn't an id .. so either use

```
document.getElementByName('AreaSorted')[0]
```

or

.. give your element an id and use `document.getElementById`, which I would recommend.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where that syntax originates from, but obviously it doesn't work (any more). To get references to forms by their name, you should use [`document.forms`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.forms).

```
document.forms.SortingForm.elements.AreaSorted.value = names.join("\n");
```

But the recommended way would be to assign an `id` to the input, and use `document.getElementById`.